# I get two kernel updates, one for Generic and one for Generic-PAE

Tags: kernel, pae

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit on notebook core 2 duo, 4GiB RAM. 
In order Ubuntu to detect and use more than 3GiB RAM, I apt-get PAE Kernel. The problem comes when there were two update of kernel, linux-generic kernel and linux-generic-pae.

Should I update linux-generic-pae kernel only? if the answer yes, how to stop update notification of linux-generic kernel? I don't want to update the wrong kernel accidentally.

Comment: My experience is that it always seems to use the pae kernel if needed (ie, you have a 32-bit system with more than about 3 GB of RAM).

Comment: how about the generic kernel?do you remove it? or using it alongside the pae?

Comment: I keep them both; if the pae were to somehow get corrupted, I may still be able to boot using the other one (assuming it's OK), just with slightly less RAM available.  Also, not necessarily helpful, but there's a link in the root directory to the kernel that's being used.  I'm not sure of the purpose of the links, unless it's to make it easier to use from GRUB.  But `/vmlinuz` is a link to the latest pae version in `/boot`.

Comment: install pae kernel as I encoutered myself that non-par kernel wont work on pae enabled kernel but its not vice-versa. So generic may not be needed when pae is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the generic kernel, remove it.

If you need it, but just don't want it updated, remove the `linux-image-generic` package.

To find out which kernel images are installed, run `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` in a terminal.

Comment: does Ubuntu use those both of kernels(generic and pae)?

Comment: It can, but only either or, not at the same time. I figured you probably won't need the generic one, as you have the pae kernel installed.