# How do I stop being offered updates for PAE kernels?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, update-manager, pae

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I get two kernel updates, one for Generic and one for Generic-PAE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129075/i-get-two-kernel-updates-one-for-generic-and-one-for-generic-pae)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 . I don't want to use PAE kernels so i am using normal kernels . but update manager giving me updates regarding PAE kernels and i dont want them .

So can i stop update manager about listing the updates regarding PAE Kernels .

Thank you .

Comment: If you *remove* existing PAE kernels it won't want to *update* them any more....  as you sow, so shall you reap, fortune favors the brave, etc. etc. :P

Comment: @izx small correction to your comment . convert it to answer by adding extra text as " select to remove listed pae kernel in update manager from synaptic manager " bottom line is : " have to remove all existed PAE kernels and then upcoming PAE kernel which was listed in update manager " Thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not remove the PAE kernels along with their headers? You don't use them anyway, and that will both solve the updates problem and free some space. To do that, use the following:

1. This command will only show what's to be removed, without removing anything.

   ```
   dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | xargs sudo apt-get --dry-run remove
   ```
2. This command will purge all unused kernels and headers.

   ```
   dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
   ```

[Info source](http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/10/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-with-one-command/)

Edit: Apparently, that command doesn't remove the metapackages, so I'd add the follwoing as well:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-generic-pae linux-image-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae
```

Comment: Hi your solution helped with removing of old/unused kernels , that we could do from Synaptic also .Thank you .great command .